# How to test if size_t -1 is not undefined, where size_t is 0?

Tags: c++, undefined, depth-first-search, adjacency-matrix, size-t

This question concerns the edges of a depth first search operating on an adjacency matrix.
Given an adjacency matrix:

```
{1,0,0,1},
{1,1,0,0},
{0,0,0,1},
{1,1,1,1}
```

I have a perfectly working DFS like so:

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<short>> matrix;

void myClass::dfs(short row, short column, std::shared_ptr<matrix> m_visited, const matrix &sky) {
    
    if (m_visited->at(row).at(column) == 1) {
        return;
    }
    m_visited->at(row).at(column) = 1; //Mark the node as visited
    if(row+1 <= sky.size()-1 && sky.at(row+1).at(column) == 1) { //Look horizontally forward
        dfs(row+1, column, m_visited, sky);
    }
    if(row-1 >= 0 && sky.at(row-1).at(column) == 1) { //Look horizontally backward
        dfs(row-1, column, m_visited, sky);
    }
    if(column+1 <= sky.at(0).size()-1 && sky.at(row).at(column+1) == 1) { //Look vertically down
        dfs(row, column+1, m_visited, sky);
    }
    if(column-1 >= 0 && sky.at(row).at(column-1) == 1) { //Look vertically up
        dfs(row, column-1, m_visited, sky);
    }
}
```

I've now been given the explicit task to **replace**
`std::vector<std::vector<short>> matrix`
with
`std::unordered_set<std::vector<size_t>> matrix`

**My problem:**
`size_t` is unsigned, so for example when `row = 0` (where row is of type `size_t`), `row -1` is undefined, and `(row -1 > 0)` evaluates to *true* on my compiler.

How can I test whether `row -1` is still inside the boundaries of my adjacency matrix using `size_t` ?

Comment: You have to test for `row > 0`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'undefined'? Integer overload is perfectly defined for unsigned types. Unlike signed.

Comment: It's not undefined. It usually underflows, which means row - 1 = size_t::max, which is far above 0

Comment: The result is certainly not undefined.   `size_t` is an unsigned integral type, subtracting `(size_t)1` from `(size_t)0` gives a perfectly well defined result equal to `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`.   `std::numeric_limits` is in the standard header `<limits>`.

Comment: It's simple math: `row - 1 > 0 <=> row > 1`

Answer (score 1):

It's simple math: `row - 1 > 0 <=> row > 1` and `column - 1 > 0 <=> column > 1`. You can replace

```
if(row-1 >= 0 && sky.at(row-1).at(column) == 1)
```

with

```
if(row >= 1 && sky.at(row-1).at(column) == 1)
```

and

```
if(column-1 >= 0 && sky.at(row).at(column-1) == 1)
```

with

```
if(column >= 1 && sky.at(row).at(column-1) == 1)
```

You should also consider replacing

```
if(row+1 <= sky.size()-1 && sky.at(row+1).at(column) == 1)
```

with

```
if(sky.size() >= 2 && row <= sky.size()-2 && sky.at(row+1).at(column) == 1)
```

and

```
if(column+1 <= sky.at(0).size()-1 && sky.at(row).at(column+1) == 1)
```

with

```
if(sky.at(row).size() >= 2 && column <= sky.at(row).size()-2 && sky.at(row).at(column+1) == 1)
```

to avoid all kinds of wrap-around.

Comment: Thanks Thomas - it seems to obvious now that I'm looking at it!

Comment: Integer values never underflow. That term is reserved for floating point values. And unsigned integer values (as the OP is asking about) never overflow by definition. Also, I don't understand the math here: `row - 1 > 0 <=> row > 1` and `column - 1 > 0 <=> column > 0`.

Comment: @IInspectable `<=>` is the mathematical equivalence relation. If `row-1 > 0` then `row > 1` and if `row > 1` then `row - 1 > 0`. "column > 0" was a typo. What are the correct terms for `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max + 1` and `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::min - 1`? What's the difference between [integer overflow/underflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) and this question?

Comment: @IInspectable: Don't be too literal about it. [WP: Integer overflow - definition variations and ambiguity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow#Definition_variations_and_ambiguity) mentions "many references" to integer underflow. "Wraparound" would be another term you could use.

Comment: @dev None of those *"references"* actually reference C++, though. And the important point being: Unsigned integers in C++ *never* overflow (or underflow, if you are more at ease with that).

Comment: @IInspectable: But they still wrap around, and if I say "it overflows" to my coworker, he knows exactly what I mean.

Comment: @dev I don't question, that unsigned integers wrap around when doing arithmetic that would result in a value that exceeds their respective range. It's just not called *"overflow"* (or *"underflow"*, for that matter). If you are talking to your coworkers, you know your audience. If you are publishing content on a website (like Stack Overflow), you do not have that luxury.

Comment: @IInspectable Do you have a reference that there is no integer underflow or overflow  in C++? It's a common term in computer science.

Comment: Where did you get the notion that I (presumably) claimed, there were no integer overflow in C++?

Comment: @IInspectable _"Integer values never underflow. That term is reserved for floating point values. And unsigned integer values (as the OP is asking about) never overflow by definition."_ I have to be more specific _"Do you have a reference that there is no **unsigned** integer underflow or overflow in C++?"_

Comment: [\[basic.fundamental\]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#2): *"Unsigned arithmetic does not overflow."*